# MySQL query to find rows with the same values in two columns, but different values in a third

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns: ord_date, invoice, part, manufacturer, part_type

I want to be able to query the table to get a list of invoice numbers that have the same part, but different manufacturer for a particular ord_date and part_type.

I've tried something like:

```
select ord_date, invoice, part, manufacturer, part_type from my_table m
where exists (
 select 1 from my_table m2
   where ord_date like '2021-05-24%'
   and part_type='car'
   and m.invoice=m2.invoice
   and m.part=m2.part
   and m.manufacturer<>m2.manufacturer)
order by invoice;
```

This works, but takes a long time.  Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Create proper indices. Do not apply LIKE to DATE datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
   where ord_date like '2021-05-24'
   and part_type='car'
   and m.invoice=m2.invoice
   and m.part=m2.part
   and m.manufacturer<>m2.manufacturer)
```

If `ord_date` is `DATETIME`, you are probably not getting what you want.

Perhaps you did not want `and m.invoice=m2.invoice`?

Add an index that contains the columns are tested by `=`.

Comment: I edited to show "ord_date like '2021-05-24%' " - I was able to implement using a stored procedure and instead am using a min max date based on the user supplied date: